# Java: Apache POI Excel Spreadsheet GUI View

Tags: java, user-interface, spreadsheet, apache-poi

My java application is using Apache POI to read/write Excel files. As far as I can see, Apache POI includes no support for an spread sheet view GUI.

So my question is this: What is the best way to display an Excel-like spreadsheet view GUI within my application? I know I could parse in all of the spreadsheet info with POI and then output it in some custom java GUI components, but that would be really ghetto... especially with java's GUI (ew).

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you open Excel sheets within Eclipse there is an internal view using the [OLE / ActiveX interface](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-ActivexSupportInSwt/index.html). Maybe you can investigate in how Eclipse/SWT achieves this and do it the same way using a RCP application as viewer.

Answer (score 0):

[Aspose.cells](http://www.aspose.com/demos/java-components/aspose.cells/java/conversion/excel-file-to-pdf.jsf) can export to PDF. Your original question is vague - is just a display/printable ok, or does it have to be interactive?

Comment: Sorry for any vagueness. Yes, I would like for it to be interactive.